# Can I convert my octet-stream / text file to a jpeg?

Tags: graphics, jpeg, file-format, binary-files

I got a file with MIME type `application/octet-stream`, off the browser cache. I have a strong feeling it's a jpeg file that I want to open.

First few files of the file:

```
Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã �JFIF������Ã¿Ã›�Â„�


""$$6*&&*6>424>LDDL_Z_||Â§


""$$6*&&*6>424>LDDL_Z_||Â§Ã¿Ã‚��Ã€"�Ã¿Ã„�0�������������������������Ã¿Ãš����Ã¶Â„cÂ£1$@Ã„
$2AÂ¤
 bÂ¤(�Ã„Ã€���@Ã„ÃÂ«Â”Ã¨Ã    {3
```

It looks like a binary file. I tried bin to jpg: https://convertio.co/jpg-converter/ but no avail.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Just rename it .jpeg? Otherwise it looks like you just need to trim the first 4 to 8 bytes. Header format expected https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

Comment: Better to use software that will read the browser cache properly as the files are not necessarily in the format you want. Use this for Firefox: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html. Use this for Chrome: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

Comment: Next time better show contents of file using hex editor like HxD.